# Use of the url parameter in Backbone.Model.extend

Tags: backbone.js

I'm new to backbone and i'm wondering what is the url parameter used for as

```
app.FormModel = Backbone.Model.extend({        
        defaults: {
            success: false,                                              
            saveData: ''
        }
    });
```

will give me a

```
Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified
```

what is url that I need to provide to extend method

According to the documentation it says

Returns the relative URL where the model's resource would be located on the server. If your models are located somewhere else, override this method with the correct logic.

What does it mean by resources.

Comment: The REST API endpoint corresponding to your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to send/retrieve data to server, backbone needs to know where the server is. The URL is exactly this.
If you don't set this property and try to sync with server, backbone will throw this exception.

http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url

Comment: Thanks, thats what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
app.FormModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
```

to

```
app.FormModel = new Backbone.Model.extend({
```